# Code automatically to save weblink on Android home screen

Tags: php, android, popup

In Android enabled devices is it possible that, if I visit any weblink through my device, a pop up appears to save link as a "Home Screen" app kind of using PHP language.

One click mobile web app is a plugin in WordPress which does this process in iOS enabled devices can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Youtube View of this in ios: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zmdBZ8KH7SQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible on Android, the user would have to bookmark the site in their browser and then manually add the bookmark to their Home screen.

The iPhone video you linked to is merely showing a popup next to the icon in Safari that allows the user to add it to the Home screen if they choose, their library just takes care of showing the popup, everything else is part of Safari.

This is also a great way to turn off users to your site and discourage them from ever visiting again.

Comment: yes i agree with you antew but if there library is showing popup in ios devices then there should be a provision to show popup on adnroid devices too and rest is taken care of by browser.